# Csharp code error main.cs(1,0): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `bool' Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Tags: boolean, bar-chart, computer-science, ninja, candlestick-chart

I wrote a code But it is showing error. My requirement is following;

need to write script,it should look at the last three bars and buy if price goes five points above the high of those bars. or it can look at every bar and if it is red, buy five points above the high.

The code i wrote is following:

bool buycondition() { int hits = 0; for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) { if(close[i] > open[i]) { hits += 1; } else if(close[i] < open[i]) { hits -= 1; } } if(open[3] > (open[2] + 5) && hits == 3) { return true; } else if(close[3] > (close[2] + 5) && hits == -3) { Enterlong(); } return false; }``

```
Remove the bugs
Why is my code not running.
suggestion is helpful for future
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it is nice to read. What error are you getting and what behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: bool buycondition()
{
    int hits = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        if(close[i] > open[i])
        {
            hits += 1;
        }
        else if(close[i] < open[i])
        {
            hits -= 1;
        }
    }
    if(open[3] > (open[2] + 5) && hits == 3)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(close[3] > (close[2] + 5) && hits == -3)
    {
        Enterlong();
    }
    return false;
}


error i am facing is following: main.cs(1,0): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `bool'
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Comment: You can edit your question to make fixes.